# Unable to remap mouse under dired in macos emacs

Tags: key-bindings, dired, osx, mouse

I'm not sure whether this should be considered an appropriate post for `emacs.stackexchange`, or whether this should go to some sort of macos forum. Please let me know if I need to ask the following question elsewhere ...

I'm running the following version of Emacs under macos (Big Sur, version 11.6.1) ...

```
GNU Emacs 27.2 (build 1, x86_64-apple-darwin18.7.0, NS appkit-1671.60 Version 10.14.6 (Build 18G95))
 of 2021-03-27
Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

I am using `dired`, and I am trying to remap `[mouse-1]` to run my own function. However, I have not been able to get `dired` to recognize this `[mouse-1]` remapping.

Here is what I have tried ...

```
(defun my-special-function ()
  (interactive)
  (message "running my special function")
  (sit-for 1)
  )

(require 'dired)
(define-key dired-mode-map [mouse-1] 'my-special-function)
(dired "/path/to/directory")
```

When I run this when positioned on a `dired` line, clicking there with `mouse-1` still runs the default `dired-find-file` function, instead of my own function.

I'm guessing that this might somehow be related to the text properties that `dired` applies within the `dired` buffer.

What can I do to under this version of emacs to get `[mouse-1]` to also get remapped to run my special function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this in a completely different way. I overrode `dired-find-file` and `dired-mouse-find-file`, as follows ...

```
(defun my-special-function ()
  (interactive)
  (message "my special function")
  (sit-for 1)
  )

(defvar my-dired-advised nil
  "*my dired stuff is already advised")

(defun my-dired-mode-hook ()
  (unless my-dired-advised
    (defadvice dired-find-file (around dired-find-file-around activate)
      (my-special-function)
      )
    (defadvice dired-mouse-find-file (around dired-mouse-find-file-around activate)
      (my-special-function)
      )
    (setq my-dired-advised t)
    )
  )

(require 'dired)
(add-hook 'dired-mode-hook 'my-dired-mode-hook)

(dired "/path/to/directory")
```

It seems like `dired` maps the mouse stuff under the covers, irrespective of any `define-key` commands involving the mouse. Simply overriding those two `dired` functions appears to be what I need to do.

Is there perhaps any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You replaced the binding for `<mouse-1>` with a binding to your command.  That should be fine, but it's not a "remapping" (which is about commands or faces, not keys).

Remapping a command is about doing something like this:

```lisp
(define-key dired-mode-map [remap dired-mouse-find-file-other-window] 'my-special-function)
```

That remaps the keys bound to command `dired-mouse-find-file-other-window` (I'm supposing that's the command you want to remap), so that those keys instead invoke your command, `my-special-function`.

See (elisp) [Remapping Commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Remapping-Commands.html).

Comment: Thank you. My understanding is that `define-key` overrides the previous key definition and replaces it, and that it doesn't simply add extra bindings. That's how it works for the dozens of non-mouse key bindings that I have been utilizing for years.

Comment: Your understanding is correct (but that's not what Emacs calls "remapping"). Forgetting about your additional binding of key `X` to your command, your `define-key` of `[mouse-1]` should, yes, bind that event to your command. What does `C-h k` followed by pressing `mouse-1` for a second or so before then releasing it tell you? It should tell you what both `<down-mouse-1>` and `<mouse-1>` are bound to.

(FWIW, I expect your question would be clearer if you removed the binding for `X`. I'm guessing now that that has nothing to do with your question.)

Comment: What I wanted to do is map `[mouse-1]` to my command. The "X" mapping I included was simply to show that the `define-key` works for non-mouse events.  However, using the `[remap dired-mouse-find-file-other-window]` as you showed above did indeed work for me.

Comment: After doing what I put in my original post, `C-h k` showed `<mouse-1>` and `<down-mouse-1>` being bound to `dired-find-file`, not to my special command.
Again, I think that `dired` does some sort of special binding of mouse events by means of text properties, or something like that.

Comment: OK. I suggest you remove mention of the `X` binding. Also, say what `C-h k` tells you, because it should tell you that `<mouse-1>` was successfully bound to your command. [Our comments crossed.] Put any info that's important in your question or answer - comments can be deleted at any time.

Comment: No, Dired doesn't do any such special binding with text properties. Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, maybe there's a bug due to MacOS or something. When I bind `[mouse-1]` to a command in `dired-mode-map` it works. `M-x report-emacs-bug`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/131443/discussion-between-hippoman-and-drew).

Comment: I moved this to "chat", because this web page suggested that I do so.

Comment: You said in a comment: *"
Running with `-Q` indeed fixes the problem. So, this is due to some sort of macos-related nonsense. I don't see this problem under linux. Thank you for your help."*
If it works with `-Q` then the problem is in your init file or some site init file (try `emacs -q`, not `-Q`, to see if the latter is the case). Bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: I already did that before responding before. It's not my own init files. It's something in the envirionment of the `Emacs.app` macos app. In any case, my defadvice-based fix and your [remap] fix both take care of the problem for me.